# Whats the equivalent of ${ANDROID_ABI} when linking static lib in Bazel?

Tags: android, android-ndk, bazel

In cmake you can specify ${ANDROID_ABI} when linking a static C++ lib to get the correct version of the library (e.g. arm64-v8a, armeabi-v7a, x86_64, etc)

```
target_link_libraries(mylib debug
        foo/lib/${ANDROID_ABI}/libfoo.a
```

What's the equivalent of that in Bazel? If I have platform specific versions of libfoo.a in foo/lib/arm64-v8a, foo/lib/arm64-v8a, foo/lib/arm64-v8a, etc. How do I link the correct on in Bazel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `select()`, `config_setting`, and `--fat_apk_cpu` for this:

```
cc_library(
  name = "foo",
  srcs = select({
    "arm64-v8a": ["foo/lib/arm64-v8a/libfoo.a"],
    "armeabi-v7a": ["foo/lib/armeabi-v7a/libfoo.a"],
    "x86": ["foo/lib/x86/libfoo.a"],
    "x86_64": ["foo/lib/x86_64/libfoo.a"],
  }),
)

config_setting(
  name = "arm64-v8a",
  values = {
    "cpu": "arm64-v8a",
  },
)

config_setting(
  name = "armeabi-v7a",
  values = {
    "cpu": "armeabi-v7a",
  },
)

config_setting(
  name = "x86",
  values = {
    "cpu": "x86",
  },
)

config_setting(
  name = "x86_64",
  values = {
    "cpu": "x86_64",
  },
)
```

and your `cc_library` rules can depend on `foo`.

Then specify `--fat_apk_cpu` on the command line, e.g. to build and package a `.so` for each platform, specify `--fat_apk_cpu=arm64-v8a,armeabi-v7a,x86,x86_64`, or some subset for what you're targeting, e.g. for an emulator `--fat_apk_cpu=x86_64`